# python multiprocessing - method not invoked with expected arguments

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, python-multiprocessing

I have a dictionary object containing an output with key as "id" and value as pandas dataframe. Size of dictionary is 9. I need to save the output of pandas dataframe in individual files on HDFS for each id. Given the time it takes to write each file as 13 min * 9 = 107 min, i am trying to parallelize this so that each file writes happens in parallel.

As part of this usecase, i am trying to use multiprocessing as below -

```
def saveOutputs(data):
    print(data[0])
  #logic to write data in file

with Pool(processes = 9) as p:
    for k, v in out.items(): #out is a dict which i need to persist in file
        data = [k,v]
        print(data[0])
        p.map(saveOutputs,data)
```

What i see is that if my id(key in dict) is 1001 , when saveOutputs is invoked as part of print in saveOutputs it print value as 1 instead of 1001 whereas in my Pool block before invoking saveOutputs, print statement is printing 1001.

I am not very clear about this behavior and not sure what is missing in incorrect.
Looking for some inputs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`p.map` doesn't work the way you may think.

When you call `p.map(function,data)`, if data is an array (as in your case), then the pool will run `function` on each element of the `data`:

```
def saveOutputs(data):
     print(data)

out={1001:"dummy", 1002:"foo", 1003:"bar"}

with Pool(processes = 9) as p:
    for k, v in out.items(): #out is a dict which i need to persist in file
        data = [k,v]
        print(data)
        p.map(saveOutputs,data)
```

will give you :

```
[1001, 'dummy']
1001
dummy
[None, None]
[1002, 'foo']
1002
foo
[None, None]
[1003, 'bar']
1003
bar
[None, None]
```

For the first couple of data two calls of `function` are made, each one with the respective element of the couple.

Comment: Thanks Jean. I am expecting Pool to run on each element of my data. If i take your data as an example, problem i am facing is that my function is not passed with complete value 1001. Individual digits of 1001 is splitted into 1,0, 0,1 which then gets used for further processing. This is breaking my system.

Comment: @Techie that should not be, but we don't know what your dict contains...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Problem is that the calling function should have arguments of type str. If you pass some objects like dictionary it doesnt works properly.